# Draw circle countdown with the libgdx

Tags: java, android, libgdx

I am prety new on LibGDX,and trying to create a circle  which shows the remaning time of the game.For that purpose I find this called [RadialSprite](https://github.com/xoppa/world/blob/master/src/com/xoppa/android/misc/RadialSprite.java),but dont know how to apply it.
what I have treid so far like this.

```
public class GameAreaScreen implements Screen{

    
    Skin skin;
    Stage stage;
    Table table= new Table(); 
    int a,b,c,result;
    float bosluk=2;
    
    
    private TextField txtFieldOperator;
    private TextField txtFieldC;
    private TextField txtFieldA;
    private TextField txtFieldB;
    private TextField txtFieldEqual;
    
    private float time=10;
    private RadialSprite rd;
    private MyGdxGame game;
    
    public GameAreaScreen(final MyGdxGame gam){
        this.game=gam;
        create();
    
    }
 


    public void create(){
    
         Texture txturecircle = new Texture(Gdx.files.internal("circle.png"));;

         TextureRegion regions= new TextureRegion(txturecircle);
          rd=new RadialSprite(regions);
          
          stage = new Stage();
         Gdx.input.setInputProcessor(stage);
        
         Skin skin = new Skin(Gdx.files.internal("data/uiskin.json"));  
        
          txtFieldA= new TextField("a Vallue", skin);
          txtFieldB= new TextField("b Vallue", skin); 
          txtFieldC= new TextField("c Vallue", skin);
          txtFieldOperator= new TextField("op", skin);
          txtFieldEqual= new TextField("=", skin);
        
         table.add(txtFieldA).pad(bosluk).width(30);
         table.add(txtFieldOperator).pad(bosluk).width(30);
         table.add(txtFieldB).width(30);
         table.add(txtFieldEqual).pad(bosluk).width(30);
         table.add(txtFieldC).pad(bosluk).width(30);
        
         table.setFillParent(true);
    
        // stage.addActor(table);
     
    }
    
    @Override
    public void show() {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        
    }

    @Override
    public void render(float delta) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        
            time -= delta; 
           
        rd.setAngle(time/10f * 360f);
        
        Log.d("TIME",String.valueOf(time));
        Log.d("angel",String.valueOf(rd.getAngle()));
        
        Gdx.gl.glClearColor(0, 0, 1, 1);
        Gdx.gl.glClear(GL10.GL_COLOR_BUFFER_BIT);

     
        game.batch.begin();
        rd.draw(game.batch, 100,100,36);
        game.batch.end();
       
        //stage.draw();  
       
        //stage.setDebugAll(true);
     
        
    }

    
    @Override
    public void resize(int width, int height) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        
    }

    @Override
    public void pause() {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        
    }

    @Override
    public void resume() {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        
    }

    @Override
    public void hide() {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        
    }

    @Override
    public void dispose() {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        
    }
```

MyGdxGame class

```
public class MyGdxGame extends Game{

    
    SpriteBatch batch;
    BitmapFont font;

    public void create() {
        batch = new SpriteBatch();
        // Use LibGDX's default Arial font.
        font = new BitmapFont();
        this.setScreen(new MenuScreen(this));
    }

    public void render() {
        super.render(); // important!
    }

    public void dispose() {
        batch.dispose();
        font.dispose();
    }
    

}
```

**Iam trying to do something like this.
[image]

any help or direction  wellcome

Comment: What does this code do? Can you post an [MCVE](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)?

Comment: It doesn't make sense to use a Task to draw something, because then it will only appear for one frame (1/60th of a second). Not sure what you're trying to do, but almost certainly the timer should be drawn in the `render` method along with everything else. Call `setAngle` on it each frame with a new value, like `rd.setAngle(timeLeft/TOTAL_TIME * 360);`.

Comment: @Tenfour04 yes u seems u are right ,but when add the your code to render function not any changes happened

Comment: You also should not be loading new Textures and Sprites in the render method. Move it to create. You are loading a new copy of the texture and leaking the old copy on every frame. Update the question with your updated code including create method so we can see what's wrong.

Comment: @Tenfour04 thanks your help.I updated my question according to your advise

Comment: I still don't understand why you have a Task. Tasks are for instantaneous effects that you want to happen at some point in the future. And you haven't said what *does* happen with your code. Do you see the sprite at all? Try removing the task completely, and then put `time -= delta; rd.setAngle(time/10f * 360f);` at the top of your `render` method.

Comment: @Tenfour04 I am sorry ,I am so beginner of the libgdx tyring to figure out.I update my question

Comment: Ok adding this game.batch.begin();
        rd.draw(game.batch, 100,100,rd.getAngle());
        game.batch.end();  seems works ,thank you your effort.